# How can we load enhanced metafile in picture control in mfc?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I am trying with this snippet but hMF always showing null.Filename stores correct path with .emf file.

```
HENHMETAFILE hMF = ::GetEnhMetaFile(fileName);
RECT rct;
GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_PIC)->GetClientRect(&rct);
CDC* dc;
dc=GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_PIC)->GetDC();

HDC hdc = dc->GetSafeHdc();

if (PlayEnhMetaFile(hdc, hMF, &rct) == 0)
{

}
DeleteEnhMetaFile(hMF);

ReleaseDC(hDC);
```

Comment: Does `filename` contain a fully qualified pathname?

Comment: Yes,
fileName = _T("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Desktop\\MyDiskFile.emf");

Comment: Is the file accessible from the user account running the code? Is this a valid Windows metafile?

Comment: Yes,It is accessible and valid metafile

Comment: Do the remarks in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getenhmetafilew) apply?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't understood about unicode or wide charater  remark.

Comment: Could you suggest any alternative method to show and emf file in mfc ?

Comment: There is no alternative.

Comment: The code works for me. Have you tried other enhanced metafiles?